# Having trouble finding the error in my code

Tags: mysql

### I am not sure what is wrong with my sql code here.  it tells me there is an error at the end but say that its at ''.  Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT  PatientID, HCPCCode, HCPCCodeCount, DischargeStatus, State, Gender, Race, Age, County, ProcedureDate, ClaimThroughDate, ICDAccessCode, ClaimID, 
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 4 THEN 4 END code4, 
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 4 THEN `Procedures` END procedures4,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 4 THEN `ICD9Codes` END ICD94,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 6 THEN 6 END code6,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 6 THEN `Procedures` END procedures6,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 7 THEN 7 END code7, 
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 7 THEN `Procedures` END procedures7,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 8 THEN 8 END code8,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 8 THEN `Procedures` END procedures8,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 9 THEN 9 END code9,
       CASE WHEN DiagnosisCodeType = 9 THEN `Procedures` END procedures9
FROM ((SELECT subquery2.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (ICDAccessCode) SEPARATOR ', ') AS ICD9Codes

FROM (SELECT subquery.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (ProcedureID) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Procedures

FROM(SELECT revenue.HCPCCode, revenue.HCPCCodeCount, patient.*, icd9.DiagnosisCodeType, procedures.ProcedureID, procedures.ProcedureDate, claims.ClaimThroughDate, icd9.ICDAccessCode

FROM `cmsdata-outpatient-2012`.revenue revenue
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `cmsdata-outpatient-2012`.patient patient
           ON revenue.ClaimID = patient.ClaimID
JOIN `cmsdata-outpatient-2012`.diagnosisicd9 icd9
           ON revenue.ClaimID = icd9.ClaimID
JOIN `cmsdata-outpatient-2012`.claims claims
           ON revenue.ClaimID = claims.ClaimID
JOIN `cmsdata-outpatient-2012`.procedures procedures
           ON revenue.ClaimID = procedures.ClaimID
AND revenue.HCPCCode IN (659, 698, 5116, 5118, 5122, 5123, 5127, 12164, 12171, 16976, 17283)
             GROUP BY ClaimID, DiagnosisCodeType) AS subquery
) subquery2)) GROUP BY ClaimID AS subquery3;
```

Comment: It probably doesn't like that you named your database `database`

Comment: Also, you seem to have one more `(` than `)`

Comment: the database part was just for show.  Its named something else but its pretty revealing

Comment: Damn no luck.  I reposted my new code.  it seems to give me a warning saying that the row was cut by the group concat.

Comment: i think i may be missing a group by statement in there somewhere.

Comment: Yep, no `GROUP BY` for your outermost `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: that didnt work, when i took it out it gave me the same warning still.

Comment: try replacing the  ticks with `'`

Comment: I tried the code i just posted, i think i am making progress.  It just says that "every derived tables must have its own alias"

Comment: Try replacing "AS subquery) subquery2)) GROUP BY ClaimID AS subquery3;" with "AS subquery) subquery2)) d GROUP BY d.ClaimID;" at the end. You seem to be aliasing the group by instead of the subquery

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` does have an upper limit on how much it can return. How much are you expecting it to hold at the various points you use it?

Comment: i believe about 427 rows.  Im very new to sql so i am not sure.

Comment: i think whats happening with the group concat is that its just creating a huge row when there should only be about 2 numbers in each group concat.

Comment: what server do you use  mysql or mssql ?

Comment: i use the mysql server

Comment: what was the issue / fix? :)

Comment: just has to add more of the GROUP BY fater all the subqueries actually lol.